# d3.js is not showing icons

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

i have been trying to insert an icon using d3.js.but i am not getting any icon when i am running it .here is my code snippet.

```
             node = svg.selectAll('g.node')
                   .data(svg_nodes, function (d) {
                        return (d && d.svg_id) || d3.select(this).attr("id");
                    })
             node.select('polygon:nth-of-type(8)') 
                .append("image")
                .attr("xlink:href", "https://github.com/favicon.ico")
                .attr("x", -8)
                .attr("y", -8)
                .attr("width", 16)
                .attr("height", 16);
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are appending an `<image>` to a `<polygon>`. An image is not a valid child of an SVG polygon, only animation elements or descriptive elements are valid children ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/polygon)).

Permissible children include:

```
   <animate>, <animateColor>, <animateMotion>, <animateTransform>, <discard>, <mpath>, <set>, <desc>, <metadata>, <title>
```

As you can't add an image to a polygon, you'll need to add it to a different parent, this also means positioning it separately.

Generally speaking, a useful approach here is often to use a parent `g` to position each polygon and image pair - this might remove the need to position `image` and `polygon` separately, but also keeps these elements paired as siblings of a common parent.

As it appears you already have a parent `g`, we only need to access it in order to append to it:

```
    node.select('polygon:nth-of-type(8)') 
        .each(function() {
            d3.select(this.parentNode)
              .append("image")
              .attr("xlink:href", "https://github.com/favicon.ico")
              .attr("x", -8)
              .attr("y", -8)
              .attr("width", 16)
              .attr("height", 16);
        })
```

*Without seeing more of your code it is not possible to say how this will position the image relative to what you want, but should at least append the image*